# How can I simplify this complex number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

So I have the complex number $\frac{(7+5i\sqrt{3})^{145}}{(92+48i\sqrt{3})^{72}}$ and I have to simplify it, with the answer being in algebraic form.
I tried using the trigonometric form of the two numbers and the dividing but $|7+5i\sqrt{3}|=\sqrt{124}$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{{5}\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{124}}$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{{7}}{\sqrt{124}}$. Did the same for the second number but then I would get numbers I cannot easily divide.
So what should I do?

Comment: What did you get for the magnitude of the denominator?  Do you notice something about the powers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A direct computation shows that$$\frac{\left(7+5\sqrt3\,i\right)^2}{92+48\sqrt3\,i}=\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i=\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)i.$$So$$\frac{\left(7+5\sqrt3\,i\right)^{12}}{\left(92+48\sqrt3\,i\right)^6}=1.$$Can you take it from here?